# How to create Mailchimp pop up sign up form that opens after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I want to create mailchimp subscriber pop up sign up form on click on my html page. Mailchimp gave me this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us13.list-manage.com","uuid":"e351f22c3447f6f906c454785","lid":"fcf6799444"}) })</script>
```

It is not working and  i dont have any idea how it works please someone solve this problem

where to put this code in html page i want to put it on my button of my website when someone clicks it sign up pop up form will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Give your button an id, like:

```
<button class="button" id="subscribe_me_button">Subscribe</button>
```

then paste yours script afterwards, I modified it such that it only displays upon the click of the subscribe_me_button. The problem is, the popup code is designed to pop up upon the first time you load the page, and disappear afterwards. It stores a cookie so that the popup doesn't annoy users of the website. However, you only want it to display when the user clicks the button.
One way to go around this is to remove the cookie everytime the user clicks the button, I have also included this in the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#subscribe_me_button').click(function() {
  document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed" + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us13.list-manage.com","uuid":"e351f22c3447f6f906c454785","lid":"fcf6799444"}) })
});
});
</script>
```